# What's the name of the (false) assumption that people in past ages were less able to reason?

Tags: ancient-history

In arguments involving past decisions or tradition, people frequently blow off the claims of tradition by using the (false) assumption that people in days gone by, or even in ancient civilizations, were less able to use their powers of reason.

Is there a term for this assumption?

Comment: Hello there, I see a lot of "what was this word" questions and answers at english.stackexchange.com

Comment: Perhaps better for english.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Note that they are kind of strict about questions tagged single-word-requests there too. See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests . Still, there are tons of them.

Comment: Exceptionalism?

Comment: The term is **stupidity.**